# In viewport, mesh is see-through, objects behind it are displayed on top

Tags: 3d-view

Many years of blender experience and just encountered this infuriating little problem:
I have a red ball mesh, a green rod mesh. 
No matter how they are positioned, the viewport displays the red ball mesh BEHIND  the green mesh. SMDH

Comment: How do I correct this so that objects are displayed normally?

Comment: Please add images that show what the problem is. If you upload a file that illustrates the issue would be the fastest way to help you. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload, then **[edit]** the resulting link into your original post.

Comment: Make sure you didn't activate X-ray for the green mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the display properties of the object that is appearing on top of other objects is not X-Ray

[image: Object Properties - X-Ray Highlighted]